# Get Term Ref From Node Referance

Tags: views

Hello after messingabout with drupalfor about the past 8 years im finally making my first 'shop' type of website. Ive been scratching my head the last week or so trying to make it as easy for me to maintain as i can. I'll have to add a lot of products and im trying to keep the workload down. anyhow....if anyone can help or suggest a better way then id love to be privvy to the information that you have.

So i have Vendors, Products and Product Ranges. Vendors will stock differant Product Ranges and then differant products in the ranges. Ive gone for a

Content Type: Vendor (term ref: Range)

Content Type: Product (term ref: Range)

So when i create a Product Node and give it a 'Range' tax term i can then show the Vendors that sell the 'Range' beside the node via tax term argument. This all works as hoped but now im starting to run into other problems.

I was wanting to create a page view of all the Products. No problems there BUT....i need to add a filter to the view for which Countrythe Product is available in. The Vendor Content Type has a 'Country' term referance field (UK< USA, etc) Somehow i need to 'pull that' from the referanced node (Vendor) and display it on the Product Page View.

I have tried adding a Relationship of ......bah i duno what im doing any more. Any relationship i use wont allow me to assign the fields with the relationship. You'll all be as confused as i am by now and will just move on leaving me in my node relationship hell :(

Comment: I could add the country tax field to the Product nodes but i wot know what vendors will be stocking the products till after i have submitted my Product node. I dont really want to have to individually add countries to the node as i would prefer to just use the data from the Vendor content type. Bah im confused again

Comment: so just to try nd clear up the confusion in my head...I have a list of Products which i want to filter by ... ope i cant get it. Maybe Views Fields could be the way to go. Sod it for now im ust gonn work without this option and if it still cant be done then im just gonna have to manually add country Tax Terms to each product in bulkif needs be.